# How to access to a class which doesn't in any package

Tags: java

I'm using IDEA to program java. And in my project src folder, I have two package "model" and "scene", and a Main.java to start my project. But now I find my classes in package cannot access to the Main, and I don't know why. My Main class is public I'm sure.

And now the only way I can find is create a new package "start" to store the Main.java, and import start package when I need Main.java. Well, I find this solution is really bad. Any advice? Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes it needs to be in a package

Comment: Creating & importing a package isn't a "really bad solution".

Comment: please share your code.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure about IntelliJ, but for Eclipse, I just put everything under a single default package. Create a package under src and put everything in there.

Answer (score -2):

You will need a package to find main from other classes, regardless of whether main is a public class or not.